# While loop not executing or not looping?

Tags: javascript

```
// require '04_wonky_coins'
// require 'rspec'
//
// # Catsylvanian money is a strange thing: they have a coin for every
// # denomination (including zero!). A wonky change machine in
// # Catsylvania takes any coin of value N and returns 3 new coins,
// # valued at N/2, N/3 and N/4 (rounding down).
// #
// # Write a method `wonky_coins(n)` that returns the number of coins you
// # are left with if you take all non-zero coins and keep feeding them
// # back into the machine until you are left with only zero-value coins.
// #
// # Difficulty: 3/5
//
// describe "#wonky_coins" do
//   it "handles a coin of value 1" do
//     wonky_coins(1).should == 3
//   end
//
//   it "handles a coin of value 5" do
//     wonky_coins(5).should == 11
//     # 11
//     # => [2, 1, 1]
//     # => [[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
//     # => [[[0, 0, 0], 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
//   end
//
//   it "handles a coin of value 6" do
//     wonky_coins(6).should == 15
//   end
//
//   it "handles being given the zero coin" do
//     wonky_coins(0).should == 1
//   end
// end
function check_coins(hand){
  for(var i=0; i<hand.length; i++){
    var coin = hand[i]
     if(coin !==0){
      return i;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
  return false;
}


function wonkyCoins(n){
  var hand = [];

  hand.push(Math.floor(n/2));
  hand.push(Math.floor(n/3));
  hand.push(Math.floor(n/4));




 while(check_coins(hand){

  var indx = check_coins(hand);


  var value = hand[indx];

  var index1 = hand.indexOf(hand[indx]);

  if (index1 > -1) {
     hand.splice(index1, 1);
  }


  hand.push(Math.floor(value/2));
  hand.push(Math.floor(value/3));
  hand.push(Math.floor(value/4));

 }

return hand.length;

}
```

the program is working but the while loop is not looping for some reasons. I suspect that there is something wrong with the condition. I am not sure if javaScript accepts that kind of conditions.However, in ruby it worked. 
can someone please explain for me why is not working please?

Comment: Is there a missing close parenthesis in the while condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a parentheses bracket to close your while loop condition parameter. Your code should really be:

```
while(check_coins(hand)){

  ... 

 }
```

If that doesn't work, it's probably the condition itself. Try:

```
while(check_coins(hand) !== null){

... 

}
```

Comment: Thank so much, yes it was the second option.

Answer (score 0):

The `while` statement should be fixed like this:

```
while (check_coins(hand)) {
```

It also appears that the `check_coins` function is only checking the first coin, and should be changed to check them all.  It also returns any one of an integer, boolean, or null value, depending on conditions - it should just return an integer (index of first non-zero coin) or null (no non-zero coins).

The fixed code would look like this:

```
function check_coins(hand){
    for (var i=0; i < hand.length; i++) {
        if (hand[i] > 0) {
          return i;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

function wonkyCoins(n) {
    var hand = [];

    hand.push(Math.floor(n/2));
    hand.push(Math.floor(n/3));
    hand.push(Math.floor(n/4));

    while ((indx = check_coins(hand)) != null) {
        var value = hand[indx];
        var index1 = hand.indexOf(hand[indx]);

        if (index1 > -1) {
            hand.splice(index1, 1);
        }

        hand.push(Math.floor(value/2));
        hand.push(Math.floor(value/3));
        hand.push(Math.floor(value/4));
    }

    return hand.length;
}
```

The code has been cleaned up to make it more readable and idiomatic Javascript.  It has not been tested, however.